# Will I run into trouble if I water houseplants with carbonated water?

Tags: houseplants, watering

I have rather a lot of partially flat liters, and wonder if I could use it as a drink for my house plants. Will purified carbonated water harm plants?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depends on whether, and how much, alkali salts have been added - Schweppes Club soda has sodium chloride, sodium bicarbonate and potassium sulfate added to it. I'd use it on the garden instead, unless you want to do a trial on a couple of plants and see what the results are.

Comment: Agreed. If the only ingredient in the ingredients list is "carbonated water" then you should be just fine.

Comment: I'll probably try it on an aloe and see what happens.

Comment: Cool question...! Never even thought about this.